# How can I receive output from another Angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular

Watched angular tutorial, and just followed the steps but now I'm struggling with @Output. I can't receive the value from another component in my home component.

I tried to use Output with EventEmitter but somehow it's not working.

Home component

```
<mat-drawer-container [autosize]="true" class="min-h-full max-w-7xl mx-auto">
  <mat-drawer mode="side" opened class="p-6">
    <app-filters (showCategory)="onShowCategory($event)"></app-filters>
  </mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content class="p-6"
    ><app-products-header (columnsCountChange)="onColumnsCountChange($event)">{{
      category
    }}</app-products-header></mat-drawer-content
  >
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Home Component TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: `home.component.html`,
})
export class HomeComponent {
  cols = 3;
  category: string | undefined;
  onColumnsCountChange(colsNum: number): void {
    this.cols = colsNum;
  }

  onShowCategory(newCategory: string): void {
    this.category = newCategory;
  }
}
```

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngIf="categories">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>CATEGORIES</mat-panel-title>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-selection-list [multiple]="false">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category"
      ><button (click)="onShowCategory(category)">
        {{ category }}
      </button></mat-list-option
    >
  </mat-selection-list>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Category Filter TS

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-filters',
  templateUrl: 'filters.component.html',
})
export class FiltersComponent {
  @Output() showCategory = new EventEmitter<string>();
  categories = ['shoes', 'sports'];

  onShowCategory(category: string): void {
    this.showCategory.emit(category);
  }
}
```

Comment: what kind of error you are getting , check oyur console and share with us the error messages

Comment: I'm getting no error. It's just not showing the value... https://youtu.be/Kbauf9IgsC4?t=3971 but for him it's showing up...

Answer (score 0):

Here you are sending data from parent component (Home Component) to a child component (Category Filter) so you should use @input decorator instead of @output. Check this article https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-filters',
  templateUrl: 'filters.component.html',
})
export class FiltersComponent {
  @Input() showCategory = new EventEmitter<string>();
  categories = ['shoes', 'sports'];

  onShowCategory(category: string): void {
    this.showCategory.emit(category);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that I am sending from parent to child? I think I am sending from child... and in video is definetly @Output used and it's working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
this.showCategory.next(category); //instead of emit.
```

I just realized I did this in my application with Angular 14. I know before it I used emit method so not sur if there is a difference but your code look good.

Other thing: you want to display in an other child (app-products-header) component so I think you need to use

```
<ng-template></ng-template>
```

in the html child

But you can pass the value through @Input to app-products-header too and display it with interpolation like any other variables